# Windows Azure VIP Swap and multiple web.configs

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, swap

We have a Windows Azure cloud service application i.e. ASP.NET MVC web application which is hosted on production slot and uses SSL , it also has ACS configured on it.

I want to deploy the same application on the Staging slot of the cloud service where we have this GUID.cloudapp.net.
Is it possible that, when my application is running in the staging slot it will refer to another web.config and when I will swap the deployment to the production slot then the application should refer another web.config?

Why I want to do this is because I have ACS configured on my application whose settings are defined in the web.config file e.g. realm.

Any feedback on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed this by modifying the web.config on Role start method.
More information at - [ACS settings in Windows Azure cscfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934992/acs-settings-in-windows-azure-cscfg/21938756?noredirect=1#21938756)