# ACS settings in Windows Azure cscfg

Tags: asp.net, azure, acs

We have a ASP.NET MVC web application configured to use ACS and deployed on the Windows Azure.

The application has all ACS settings like realm in the web.config file.

Is it possible to have all ACS settings or at least realm setting in the Windows Azure cloud service configuration file? so that it can be modified directly from the portal at any time and there is no need to re-deploy the application?

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Vittorio describes a solution in his blog post at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2011/05/31/EDIT-AND-APPLY-NEW-WIF-S-CONFIG-SETTINGS-IN-YOUR-WINDOWS-AZURE-WEBROLE-WITHOUT-REDEPLOYING/.